# Is there a way to connect cake php application with codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, cakephp

I am working on an online tutoring website that is made in cakephp 2.4 . I need to add a new part to it . However i have expertise in codeigniter and want to make this part in code igniter . Is it possible for me to connect the working cakephp part of the website with newly built part in codeigniter .

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea if the goal is just to add new functionality to an existing website. Can you describe that new part ?

Comment: I need to make a psychometric test to attract users to our website. I have got the contract to maintain and further develop this website . I am finding it very hard to adapt to cake php syntax after working in codeigniter for a long time . Also there is a deadline involved . This website is already developed 70% in cake php 1.3.31 and 30% in cake 2.4. So i was wondering if i could futher develop it in codeigniter keeping the cake part intact .

Comment: Well, this is my opinion but, I think that functionality isn't complex enough to justify two different apps and you really should try to get along with cakephp for the sake of maintainability and maybe also for your reputation. However, if you really want to do that. You can probably put your CI app at the root and relocate the cakephp app in a subfolder and then play with htacess to hide those paths. Good luck :)

Comment: I completely agree with you Adrien that developing in cake will be the most conventional approach.However please elaborate a little about your reply as i would prefer to go the code igniter way under the circumstances.As I understand from your suggestion :
1) I should place the code ignitor folder in the root of cpanel.
2) Would it be necessary to move my cakephp folder (exam in may case).
3) What shall be done with the. Htaccess. Test will be in Jquery wizard or a custom bootstrap theme. I need to pass studentID from cake part to codeigniter part. Kindly provide details about this part,

Comment: 1/ yes but that can be the opposite, Cake at root and CI in folder 2/ I don't know Cakephp so I don't don't know if some CP files can conflict with CI files (e.g index.php) to avoid that you should separate the frameworks into different folders. 3/ Some URL rewritting to keep the consistency in the url when the user will go from one to another framework and to hide that 4/ The easiest is to pass the studentID through GET I guess.